# Is there a definitive way to install amdgpu graphics drivers on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 22.04, xorg, amd-graphics

I've been working with Ubuntu 22.04 on my laptop for ages and now I finally saved up to buy a desktop. My AMD GPU is a Radeon RX 6950XT. I was told that I have to install the AMD graphics drivers, because there are applications like Steam that can't be launched from the start menu unless you download the drivers. Whenever I try to open up Steam from the start menu it just opens then closes constantly, which I was told that you need to download the AMD drivers in order to solve this issue.

Also whenever I type the `update-initramfs` command it always gives me a few warnings saying that amdgpu firmware was missing, but whenever I use Ubuntu 22.04's `amdgpu-install` package I've been getting errors. The first error I got was `There were errors while processing amdgpu-dkms`. I researched and I *assume* I was just using the wrong package, so I downloaded a different package that a person on a thread said was definitely the version for Ubuntu 22.04, but installing the package gave me an unmet dependencies error message saying that some dependencies were uninstallable.

I've really searched up and down to try to find a way to install amdgpu graphics drivers, and I really cannot find a solid way to do it without issue. Furthermore actually, when I said that there a dependency issue someone in the thread said to downgrade the dependencies list and that actually worked last night, but when I booted up my computer this morning it didn't list xorg on the login screen and if I go to the "About" section of settings it doesn't list my graphics card as the one I have. Instead it says that my graphics are llvm.

I've already clean wiped my Ubuntu 22.04 system several times and I thought it got it working this time, but it seems like I have a driver issue again. One thing to note though, whenever it was correctly detecting my graphics card whenever I typed the command `sudo update-initramfs -k all -c` it gave me several errors saying that amdgpu firmware was "possibly missing", but now after it detects my graphics card as llvm it doesn't show me this error at all anymore. I'm assuming that the system isn't even using the amdgpu graphics anymore and just defaulted to whatever "llvm" is.

That was just additional information. M main reason for coming here to ask a question is I wanted to know is there actually a way to install amdgpu graphics drivers on Ubuntu 22.04? I read that I might need to downgrade to 20.04 because some packages don't even work at all in jammy, but I wanted to ask here if there is actually a working way to make this just finally work for me.

Comment: I was told that I have to install the drivers. Cause there applications like Steam that completely do not open up from the start menu unless you download the drivers (which is what I was told). Whenever I try to open up Steam from the start menu it just opens then closes constantly, which I was told that you need to download the amd drivers in order to solve the issue. Also whenever I typed the `update-initramfs` command it always gave me a few warnings saying that amdgpu firmware was missing

Comment: Ignore any messages about 'possibly missing firmware' they are red-herrings, it always says that for AMD GPUs. You should not need to download any additonal AMD drivers as they should be in the kernal already. It might be worth re-installing Ubuntu again, updating all packages `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`, then installing Steam `sudo snap install steam`, then open it from a terminal and investigate the error messages there.

Answer (score 3):

until roughly 1 hour ago I had similar issues. Now I'd like to publish my solution and hope that it may help some of you ;)

## Prerequisites:

First of All - My Setup:

```
AMD Ryzen 9 7950X (With integrated AMD graphics)
AMD RX 6650XT GPU
On MSI MPG X670E Carbon WIFI Mainboard

As OS I'm running a fresh install of Kubuntu 22.04.3
(Should be identical to Ubuntu 22.04.3)
```

Straight after install i ran

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo shutdown -h 0 (and subsequent reboot)
```

which got me to Kernel Version

```
6.2.0-33-generic (from uname -r)
```

At that point neither the Ryzens integrated graphics nor the RX6650XT were working, as indicated by the output of `sudo lshw -c video` (All `*-display` entries marked as `UNCLAIMED`)

## FIX:

1. Install the deprecated libssl1.1 which was installed on a different machine of mine with an older Version of Ubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15.0)

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl/libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libssl1.1_1.1.0g-2ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

2. Install `amdgpu-install`

```
wget http://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/5.7/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i amdgpu-install_5.7.50700-1_all.deb
```

3. Install AMD Drivers

```
amdgpu-install -y --accept-eula --opencl=rocr --opengl=mesa --vulkan=pro
```

Remarks:

- Read the AMD Docs regarding the options, depending on your graphics card you may need other parameters
- I ran `sudo update-grub2` after installation was finished, so maybe do that aswell for good measure ;)

4. Reboot

```
shutdown -h 0
```

Hope this helps and best of luck :D

Comment: This works for me using this amdgpu, `amdgpu-install_5.7.50702-1`. Especially the amdgpu-install options: `amdgpu-install -y --accept-eula --opencl=rocr --opengl=mesa --vulkan=pro`

Comment: it doesn't seem work with [latest driver v6.0](https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/23.40.2/ubuntu/jammy/amdgpu-install_6.0.60002-1_all.deb). Says 'Unsupported OS: /etc/os-release ID 'pop''

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and i've read few similar ones over the last time. But not even one **generic** solution. Even not in the official AMD-Forum. ‍♀️

But i came a little further on my **specific** solution doing this:

Installed the amd-drivers from: https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/23.10.3/ubuntu/focal/amdgpu-install_5.5.50503-1_all.deb

Modified the repo Adresses of all the AMD-releated-repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` from `focal` to `jammy`

```
sudo apt update
sudo update-initramfs
sudo reboot
sudo amdgpu-install --usecase=graphics,opencl --vulkan=amdvlk --opencl=legacy
```

I'm not 100% sure, what exactly the options of `amdgpu-install` do, and if the proprietary driver runs as expected. But Steam launches without any problems...